# Using pull down resistor?

Tags: voltage, current, usb, induction

I have made an application with 3 [Omron IR LED Photo sensors](https://www.tme.eu/nl/details/e3jk-r2m2/standaard-foto-elektrische-sensors/omron/e3jk-r2m2-2m/). This sensor can't be bought anymore, but here is the [datasheet](https://www.tme.eu/Document/cb76389d2852c2851f33d3f660510f98/e3jk.pdf).

I used a transformer 230 AC - 24 AC. Due to induction? the sensor output is 1.2V instead of 0 V. The sensor output is connected with a D-Sub 9 connector which leads to my computer where I made a program to run the setup.

What is the best and most efficient way to reduce the 1.2V to 0 Volts? Is using a Pull Down resistor the best solution, what kind of resistor do I need to use in that case?

This is the electronic schematic: I don't think the '3' and 'PE' are connected properly, right?
[image: Electronic Schematic]

Comment: Could you edit your post and provide detailed information on those Omron devices?

Comment: Thank you for adding the link, but it is about a whole family of devices. We need the specific device type you got. More specifically, we need to figure out if it is a PNP type or NPN type.

Comment: Okay thanks. I fixed the model and datasheet.

Comment: So the model is R2M2? How have you connected to the computer? Which port, is is special hardware?

Comment: Yes it's the R2M2 model. I have connected is with a Sub-D connector which I can plug into my computer

Comment: You said that already, but did not answer how is it wired to Sub-D connector, and which port this is? Serial port? Some other port?

Comment: I connected to ports 4, 6,7 and 8. The 24V signal should be sent ports 6 and 8

Comment: I think I found an error in my wiring, but I'm not sure. I will test this asap

Comment: Okay, when I use a 24DC instead of a 24AC everything works, so I will probably switch to a DC power supply

Answer (score 0):

The sensor model E3JK-R2M2 2M has a single-pole dual-throw relay output. You do not need a pulldown resistor. You can apply a "digital high" voltage level to one contact of the relay (black or gray, according to the datasheet). A "digital low" to the other, and connect the common (white) to your computer. The relay output will then alternate between high and low.

Whatever "digital high" and "digital low" means in this context depends on the signal levels your computer input expects too see.

Do note that relay contacts may bounce during switchover. If you cannot compensate for this in software you'll have to research "hardware switch debouncing".